# Plot a x=1, y=1 and another function in R

Tags: r, plot

I am new to R, and I am trying to do what it seems to be the simplest thing, but for the love of god, I cannot find out how to do it!

As the title says, I want to plot x=1, y=1 and y=1/(2*x), preferably with different colors, and after that, I want to paint the area between the x,y axis and the lines ploted. Something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: abline(h=1); abline(v=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. For example, using `library(ggplot2)` you can do

```
# define how far beyond the intersection we calculate curve values
xmax = 1.1        
xmin = 1/(2*xmax)

# calculate coordinates of the curve
x = seq(xmin, xmax, length.out = 100)
y = 1/(2*x)

# create polygon coordinates that follow the curve and ...
# ...extend down the staight lines to infinity
poly = data.frame(
  x = c(x[x<1 & y<1], 1,   1,    -Inf, -Inf, 0.5), 
  y = c(y[x<1 & y<1], 0.5, -Inf, -Inf, 1, 1))

ggplot(data.frame(x,y), aes(x,y)) +
  geom_polygon(data = poly, fill='yellow') +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=1)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=1)) +
  coord_equal(1, c(0,1), c(0,1))
```

[image]